# How to delete cached files on apache server after prod deploy

Tags: angular, apache, caching, browser

I'll try to explain my problem. I run an Angular 7 Project on an apache server. The files are stored in the htdocs directory.

The problem that I have is, that after I deploy a new version of my angular project, some files don't show the new content and even throw errors. But if I reload the page, everything works fine, until I close the tab and reopen it in a new tab.

I already put the hashing-output to all, I guess normally that should solve this issue, but not in this case. Does anyone have an ideas?

A quick resume:

Deploy -> open page in new tab -> **old content** -> refresh page -> **new content** -> close tab and reopen again -> **old content**

If I clear the cache manually, everything works fine, even if I reopen the page in a new tab. I hope someone can help me, it is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Hash Angular files while building**

**Angular** has a built in hashing mechanism to ensure updated files are not cached. To activate this functionality you have to add the property `"outputHasing": "all"` to the build configurations in your angular.json file.
Alternatively you can build your project with the command: `ng build --output-hashing=all`

**2) Add server side Cache-Control headers**

However, Angular does not ensure the index.html file isn't cached. Server-side response headers can take up this task. Cache-Control is a header that you can configure on your web server to add to all outgoing requests, which will tell the browser and CDNs how to cache your content.

On **Apache** you should set these cache control headers in your main configuration file 'httpd.conf'. In case you can't access this file due to hosting limitations you can set it in your '.htaccess' file. To not cache the index.html file use following cache control headers:

```
#Initialize mod_rewrite
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
  FileETag None
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 12 Jan 1980 05:00:00 GMT"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

NB: Make sure that the mod_headers are enabled in your main configuration file. Following line should be uncommented (without the #).

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
```

While calling the latest version of your page (f.ex. by refreshing without using cached content `CTRL+SHIFT+F5`) you should see these cache control headers in your response headers. You can verify these headers in the Inspect > Network tab in your browser.

**3) Handle previously cached files**

All versions of your index.html file that were cached in your clients browser -before you added the new cache control headers- will still be cached. To overcome this issue you should use different URL's. This can be done by using a new domain name (as long as you do not care about SEO), changing the route or by adding a URL parameter (without touching SEO).

After building your Angular project as described above and adding this configuration on your Apache web server, users will always get the newest version of your page.